# linq operators like in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

HI,

I have 3 tables: **Clips**, **Books** and relationships between **ClipBook**

**Problem is:**
i need get **book** that has **bookID=4** with some clips i mean many-to-many

in simple text sql it will be something like this:

`select * from Clips where clipID in (select clipID from ClipBook where bookID=4)`

**Question is:**

How can i do this with **Linq** without operator **Join** of course

Comment: I don't unterstand why you don't want to use join for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this could be a solution;

```
from cb in ClipBooks
where cb.BookID == 4
select cb.Clip;
```

or

```
ClipBooks.Where(cb => cb.BookId == 4).Select(cb => cb.Clip);
```

Answer (score 1):

the Contains method is in Linq converted into the IN operator, example:

```
String[] cities = {"London", "Paris", "Madrid"};

from p in context.Person
where cities.Contains(p.Adress.City)
select p
```

is translated into a sql clause like:  .. `WHERE a.City in ('London', 'Paris', 'Madrid')` where a is the Address table alias after the join with the Person table.

edit:

you could write a single query without a subquery, but this will be converted to a join most probably:

```
var clips = (from c in context.ClipBooks
             where c.BookID == 4
             select c.Clip).Distinct();
```

or

```
var clips =  from c in context.Clip
             where c.ClicBooks.Any( cb => cb.BookID == 4)
             select c
```

Any is translated in Exists()